# Factorygirl can't create factories in the db for javascript steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have this rspec scenario:

```
background do
  Factory.create(:project, :name => "NAME", :url_name => "url name")
end


scenario "A not logged in user with no cookies goes to the root url and chooses a project", :js => true do
  visit root_path
  #^ this fires up a browser
  ...
end
```

When I call the debugger in the controller action that gets hit for the root_path, no `Project`s exist. When I remove the `:js => true`, the project does exist. Any suggestions?

I'm using rails 3 with jquery and factory_girl_rails 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable transactional fixtures. See https://github.com/lailsonbm/contact_manager_app